# How to load JPE image file?

Tags: delphi, jpeg, delphi-xe2

This code:

```
uses
  Vcl.Imaging.jpeg...
...
ThisPicture := TPicture.Create;
try
  ThisPicture.LoadFromFile('MyImage.JPE'); // error
  ...
finally
  ThisPicture.Free;
end;
```

generates this error:

```
EInvalidGraphic: Unknown picture file extension <.jpe>
```

ALTHOUGH **Vcl.Imaging.jpeg** is used. JPG and JPEG can be loaded without problems.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) explains that **.jpg, .jpeg, .jpe .jif, .jfif, .jfi** are extensions of the JPEG format.

So how can I use **LoadFromFile('MyImage.JPE')** without error?

Comment: Call `TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('jpe', 'JPE Image File', TJPEGImage);` somewhere at your program startup.

Comment: @TLama Both solutions from TLama and David Heffernan do work, thanks to both! But since generally I prefer the most simple solutions I'd like to use your solution, so please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JPE extension is not registered by the Delphi JPEG code. Hence the error. Since you know the image type you can load it directly into a TJPEGImage object:

```
Image := TJPEGImage.Create;
Image.LoadFromFile(...);
```

And the assign to the picture control.

```
 ThisPicture.Assign(Image);
```

Or the simpler solution of registering the JPE extension so that `TPicture` associates it with `TJPEGImage`. This can be done using [`TPicture.RegisterFileFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.RegisterFileFormat):

```
uses
  Vcl.Imaging.JConsts, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg;
....
TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('jpe', sJPEGImageFile, TJPEGImage);
TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('jif', sJPEGImageFile, TJPEGImage);
TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('jfif', sJPEGImageFile, TJPEGImage);
TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('jfi', sJPEGImageFile, TJPEGImage);
```

For what it is worth, the documentation of `RegisterFileFormat` contains this rather quaint line:

> The AExtension parameter specifies the three-character system file extension to associate with the graphic class (for example, "bmp" is associated with TBitmap).

Don't worry about the suggestion that extensions have to be exactly three characters in length. That is simply a documentation error.

Comment: You cannot `Assign()` a `TJPEGImage` to `TPicture.Graphic` unless it already points at an existing `TJPEGImage`. Better to `Assign()` to the `TPicture` itself instead so it updates the `Graphic` regardless of its current type: `ThisPicture.Assign(Image);`